# Sidenav mode 'over' vs 'side' in Material 2 with angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want the mode for `sidenav` to toogle between `over` and `side` depending on the screen size.

I found below example, but the component media seems to be deprecated for material. What is best practice?

```
constructor(public sidenav: SidenavService,
            public media: Media) {
}

hasMedia(breakSize: string): boolean {
    return this.media.hasMedia(breakSize);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by ObservableMedia, but the code could probably be better:

Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from "@angular/core";
import {ObservableMedia} from "@angular/flex-layout";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public media:ObservableMedia ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

template:

```
<md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav  mode="{{media.isActive('gt-sm') ? 'side' : 'over'}}" align="begin" class="md-whiteframe-4dp" opened >
      <md-nav-list>
        ...
      </md-nav-list>
    </md-sidenav>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's easier :

```
<md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav [mode]="myMode" opened="true">
    <!-- Your content + close the tags -->
```

In your Component

```
myMode = 'side';
```

Now all you have to do is get the document width and chose when to change the mode.

Comment: That I know, but what about the screen size?

Comment: 10 seconds on Google man ... `let width = document.body.clientWidth;`

Comment: It seems, that you don't understand my question. I want to implement the component, so hasmedia can be called like this hasMedia('gt-sm') and I don't want to define my own width method. I am looking for the best practice in material. I have looked into flexlayout but can't see how I can implement into the has media method.

Comment: What I'm telling you is the simplest way to manage the sidenav. If you want to create a component that can handle the sidenav, then you're right, I didn't get the point, and I won't be able to help you, sorry :/

Comment: Thanks for trying. But I thought my example already indicated that I wanted to implement as method in the component. But thanks any way.

Comment: "I want the mode for sidenav to toogle between over and side depending on the screen size", I didn't read through it, I'm very litteral ahah ! Still, by looking at it, I can see that my method still works for an isolated component

Comment: If you're curious, solve this with the media:ObservableMedia. I have attached a example